# Should I write "feature in" or "is featured in"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> The Department of Statistics at XXX University, which also features in a wide spectrum of research topics, is my dream school.

I am writing my personal statement to apply for graduate school. Is there any mistakes in the above sentence?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence.  We need a bit more information, Mariana.  Are you using *features* to mean *plays a significate part/role in*?  That translates to *The department of statistics also plays a significant role in a wide spectrum of research papers.*  Is that close to what you are saying?  If so I would use *significant role*.  It is more easily understood.

Comment: Opinion: they already know more about their own department than you do, and they probably want to know why you would make a good student at the school. Telling them what you hope to achieve and what you might be able to contribute would be more productive than telling them you are dreamer.

Comment: @EllieK Their department's feature is a wide spectrum of research topics. I am also a multidisciplinary person. So this program is a great fit for me.

Comment: I recommend looking up in a dictionary what "features in" means. You don't seem to have a good grasp of it.

Comment: I am attracted to the Dept of Stats at X because of the breadth of its research topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need the "in" in "features in a wide spectrum." The way you're using it, "features" is a transitive verb, with "spectrum" as its object (like "the hotel *features* comfy beds"). (The construction "features in" works in reverse: "Comfy beds feature in this hotel's best rooms.")
2. *Maybe an issue, maybe not:* Right now the sentence says "The Department of Statistics ... is my dream school." If you mean that XXX University is your dream school, you should reorganize the sentence (maybe "XXX University, whose Department of Statistics features a wide spectrum of research topics, is my dream school").
3. *Maybe an issue, maybe not:* The word "also" should only be included if the material before this sentence would make it make sense (perhaps you just mentioned other things about the department, or other places that feature a wide spectrum of research topics).